# Override field module function in custom module?

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

I want to override [`field_sql_storage_field_storage_write()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21modules%21field_sql_storage%21field_sql_storage.module/function/field_sql_storage_field_storage_write/7.x), defined in /modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module.

I tried with `MYMODULE_field_storage_write_alter($entity_type, $entity, $op, $fields)`, but it doesn't work.

How should I override that function?

Comment: This question has neither _CODE NEED TO MODIFY_ embedded (why not just name the CORE function with link to http://api.drupal.org?) not your own effort to show what to alter.

Comment: done, url added

Comment: My comment above asked for what you want to accomplish in weird words ;). I added an answer but it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [hook_field_storage_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_storage_info_alter/7.x)

Other candidates are

1. [hook_field_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_insert/7.x)
2. [hook_field_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_update/7.x)